# How do I customize the tell-a-friend "thank you" template?

Tags: tell-a-friend

I'm using the standard tell-a-friend code from the EE Docs. Where do I find the "thank you" page template that comes up after emailing an entry using the tell-a-friend tag? I'd like to style it to look like the rest of my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[`return`](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/email/tellafriend.html#return)** parameter on the `exp:email:tell_a_friend` tag to specify a template you want to use as the confirmation (thank you) page. It can be any template you want, customized as needed.

If you're talking about the "interstitial" page where a message is shown for a few seconds before redirecting, *that* is a system message and to customize it you'll need to go to *CP > Design > Message Pages > User Messages* or use an add-on like [Custom System Messages.](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages)

Comment: I think it is the "interstitial" template(s) I want to edit. The return parameter is what that page returns to, it seems. I found the template -- thanks!

Comment: OK great. It's not mandatory, but if I've answered your question you have the option to mark this answer as "accepted." See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)